# Constant Current Charger

Tags: batteries, charger, current-limiting, constant-current, pid-controller

I have done a simple charger by using a opamp UA741 and a current limiter. The current limit method is using 2 transistors and a resistor to limit at 3A. However, this current limit was not limit the current. Next, i have tried by using LM317&LM338 the voltage regulator. The result is still not constant when connect to the battery as load.

Hence i would like to reconstruct a constant current part.
[image]
[image]

Thank you for sharing. I am highly appreciate.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: _”this current limit was not limit the current”_ Please clarify. Show with oscillograms expected versus observed behavior.

Comment: I would like to do a Constant current at 3A. But with the current limiter circuit i have tried it is not able to achieve it.

Comment: The current limiter that used 2 transistor method is not limiting the current. I have tried construct the circuit and test. The graph shows the current constant and voltage increase until 80% the current decrease and voltage constant.

Answer (score 2):

Where did the regulator schematic come from?  It has several problems.

The 741 opamp requires a minimum of 10 V across its power pins for normal operation, but your schematic has this limited to 5 V with a zener diode.

There is no decoupling capacitance across the 741's power pins.  This can lead to oscillation and other erratic operation.

With the 741 running on 5 V, or even 10 V, the output never will be greater than 15 V to cause the FET to conduct.

There is no current sensing device or component, and no feedback to cause constant current regulation.

You show the 741 being powered by 5 V, but when R6 is turned all the way up there will be over 7 V on pin 2.

The two-transistor current limit circuit you show is known to work very well.  You say it did not work for you, but you did not say why it did not work.  In what manner it did not perform for you?

Comment: My *guess* is that the transistors blew up because they were asked to dissipate several watts without any heatsink

Comment: the minimum supply voltage for 741 is 5v-15v. When i connect to the load the IC runs correctly after I vary the trimmer pot. When pin 2 is more than pin 3 itt is in off condition from what i have tested. When i connect this two transistor limit current with the above circuit to the load it is limit to certain current but not constant as CC when charging and become CV when the battery is almost full.